# I have an svg image, is there is a way to convert it into canvas but not very complecated code, i want to use that in dynamic size chart

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, xhtml

Here is the svg code

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 595.3 841.9;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: #040305;
    }

    .st1 {
      fill: #5E459C;
    }
  </style>
  <g>
    <path class="st0" d="M322.2,837h143.3c19.6,0,37.1-15.6,39.1-34.7c7.8-77.7-7.9-175.3-22.6-211.1c-4.6-11.1-10.8-21.3-17.4-32.2
        c-18-29.5-38.3-63-36.2-129.5c2-62,37.1-104.1,57.9-123.7c10.5-9.9,22-28.1,22.6-44.9c1.7-48.9-12.9-83.6-25.4-104.1
        c-9.2-15.2-29.6-24.1-44.6-25.8c-17.8-2.1-50.7-7.6-71.1-20.7c-14.8-9.4-19-28.3-19.8-43c4.7-6,7.7-12.7,7.7-20.2
        c0-23.1-26-41.1-59.2-41.1c-33.2,0-59.2,18.1-59.2,41.1c0,7.6,3.1,14.5,8,20.6c-0.9,14.6-5.1,33.2-19.9,42.5
        c-20.4,13-53.3,18.6-71.1,20.7c-15.4,1.8-35.7,11.3-44.6,25.9c-12.5,20.5-27,55.2-25.4,104c0.6,16.8,12.1,35.1,22.6,44.9
        c20.8,19.6,56,61.7,57.9,123.7c2.1,66.5-18.3,100-36.3,129.6c-6.6,10.8-12.8,21.1-17.4,32.1c-14.7,35.8-30.5,133.4-22.6,211.1
        c1.9,19.1,19.5,34.7,39.1,34.7h103.8 M296.5,32.3c19.8,0,32.9,8.9,32.9,14.8s-13.1,14.8-32.9,14.8c-19.8,0-32.9-8.9-32.9-14.8
        S276.7,32.3,296.5,32.3z M253.3,836.9h47 M473.6,799.1c-0.4,3.3-4.4,6.6-8.1,6.6H127.7c-3.7,0-7.7-3.3-8.1-6.6
        c-7.2-71.8,7.3-164.1,20.5-196.1c3.6-8.8,9-17.6,15.2-27.9c19.2-31.6,43.1-70.9,40.7-146.7c-2.3-73.2-43.4-122.6-67.8-145.4
        c-6.5-6.1-12.6-17.1-12.7-23.2c-1.4-41.1,10.6-69.9,20.8-86.8c2.5-4.1,13-10.1,21.6-11.1c24.9-3,59.8-9.8,84.2-25.3
        c19.7-12.6,28.4-32.8,32.1-51.3c6.8,1.9,14.3,3,22.2,3c8.1,0,15.6-1.1,22.6-3c3.6,18.5,12.3,38.7,32.1,51.4
        c24.4,15.6,59.3,22.4,84.2,25.3c8.9,1.1,19.1,6.9,21.6,11.1c10.3,16.9,22.2,45.7,20.8,86.8c-0.2,6-6.3,17.1-12.8,23.2
        c-24.3,22.9-65.4,72.2-67.7,145.4c-2.4,75.9,21.5,115.1,40.7,146.7c6.2,10.2,11.6,19.1,15.2,27.9
        C466.3,635.1,480.8,727.4,473.6,799.1z" />
  </g>
  <circle class="st1" cx="100.1" cy="253.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="494.1" cy="253.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="144.1" cy="149.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="455.1" cy="149.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="147.1" cy="329.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="180.1" cy="450.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="161.1" cy="532.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="433.1" cy="532.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="413.1" cy="450.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="446.1" cy="329.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="110.1" cy="659.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="103.1" cy="797.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="489.1" cy="797.2" r="15.4" />
  <circle class="st1" cx="483.1" cy="659.2" r="15.4" />
</svg>
```

I just want to increase and decrease the Blue Points along with mannequin edges so that my image change according to the dimension i have enter. is there is way to convert into canvas and achieve that

Comment: convert SVG to canvas is easy because all canvas commands are base on SVG syntax. In your case you can also keep your SVG and move your circles directly with javascript.

Comment: @MisterJojo Thanks for the answer! I used an online conversion tool to switch from SVG to HTML canvas, but the resulting code is quite lengthy. Since I'm not very familiar with HTML canvas in JavaScript, could you please provide a more concise example that I can better understand? Your assistance is much appreciated!